# ionic 1 angularjs 1 create a pages and navigate with $location

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic framework. I created a blank ionic project and I designed the login and register page, using angularjs.

my problem is, I want to go to another page, when the user click on a button. So I added ng-click on the button and defined a function, I tried $location.href, but the page is opening without ionic css. I am new to this framework, how can I create a new page/view and link it to the button. Thank you

Comment: You can solve this with ui-router adding different levels with different layouts. No need to $location that way

Comment: any sample for this ? I don't have any idea about ui-router

Comment: I could give you some sample code, but if you don't know a thing about ui-router it will be worthless. You should take a look at the documentation, specifically to nested routes. What you will want to do is have a base state which is "login" and then some state that is "app" (or w/e). You go to "app" when you are logged in. So you have app.index, app.someThing, etc.

Comment: ok can you upload or send the sample? thank you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HKSHCsB8 | Here you have. I tried to explain with comments, but again: read the ui router documentation so you get an idea of how states and nested states work. Otherwise you will be struggling like crazy.